# Dabeng OrgChart Format Array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, orgchart

i have Output Like this from data.php, iam use https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart

```
[
{"title":"306","relationship":"30","name":"HARDWARE & ","parentid":"30"},
{"title":"296","relationship":"476","name":"IT  DOCUMENTATION","parentid":"476"},
{"title":"596","relationship":"30","name":"MAGANG MIS DEPARTMENT","parentid":"30"},
{"title":"345","relationship":"30","name":"NETWORK SYSTEM STAFF","parentid":"30"},
{"title":"184","relationship":"476","name":"PROGRAM ANALYST","parentid":"476"},
{"title":"46","relationship":"476","name":"PROGRAMMER","parentid":"476"},
{"title":"476","relationship":"30","name":"SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT ","parentid":"30"},
{"title":"580","relationship":"30","name":"SYSTEM & NETWORK S","parentid":"30"},
{"title":"604","relationship":"580","name":"SYSTEM & SECURITY ","parentid":"580"},
{"title":"48","relationship":"306","name":"TECHNICAL SUPPORT","parentid":"306"}
]
```

from this ajax

```
    $('#chart-container').orgchart({
        'data' : 'data.php',
        'nodeContent': 'title',
        'nodeId': 'id',
        'exportButton': true,
        'exportFilename': 'MyOrgChart'
    });
```

But This Not Working ? thks

[Yapp This the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO1id.png)

Comment: What have you tried? What's happening?  Do you have this somewhere publicly viewable? "This not working" tells us little.

Comment: Okay , iam edit my post , cek this picture  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO1id.png

Answer (score 0):

replace 'data.php' as an ajax response with json format not a URL. Also, your relationships should be in "1/0" of "111" = "hasParent,hasSibling,hasChildren" not the parentid.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of plugin orgchart can attach relationship property to the datasource behind the scenes. So you can remove relationship filed in the datasource and use json object to initialize orgchart rather than an array.

```js
$('#chart-container').orgchart({
 'data' : jsonObj,
 'nodeContent': 'title',
 'nodeId': 'id',
 'exportButton': true,
 'exportFilename': 'MyOrgChart'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use kendo org chart, problem may solve

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.621/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
    <div id="orgchart"></div>

    <script>
        var data = [
            { id: 1, name: "Gevin Bell", title: "CEO"},
            { id: 2, name: "Clevey Thrustfield", title: "COO", parentId: 1},
            { id: 3, name: "Carol Baker", title: "CFO",  parentId: 1 },
            { id: 4, name: "Kendra Howell", title: "CMO",  parentId: 1},
            { id: 5, name: "Sean Rusell", title: "Financial Manager", parentId: 3},
            { id: 6, name: "Steven North", title: "Senior Manager",  parentId: 3 },
            { id: 7, name: "Michelle Hudson", title: "Operations Manager", parentId: 2},
            { id: 8, name: "Andrew Berry", title: "Accountant", parentId: 5 }            
        ];

        $("#orgchart").kendoOrgChart({
            dataSource: data
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's good to see you being an active member of this community, for future answers make sure to give a full explanation of what the problem was and why your answer solves it. Also make sure to make you code snippets as small and concise as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Mercury for your wise advise, sure I will do next time.